# Free Games on Steam?

Tags: steam

Is there anywhere I can look at a list of all games steam is offering for free?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is a [Free to Play](http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Free%20to%20Play/) category on the Steam store.

In addition to this there is a popular and seemingly up-to-date [list of free Steam games](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=851573) on the Steam Forums.

Comment: They don't even list them in the "All games below 5 €" list :(

Comment: Note that the F2P category only includes pay2win games. Actually free games like Alien Swarm are not included.

Answer (score 4):

- There is a Genre called Free-To-Play
- Demos are also free to play

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose `"Advanced Search"` and narrow your search to `"Free To Play"'.